# Python pandas: Two ways null values table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
ID - Age - Sex
1 - 20 - Null
2 - 40 - F
3 - 40 - M
4 - Null - M
5 - 18 - Null
```

And I would like to know if the nulls distribution in the age data is equivalent between both sex, so a two ways table like the one below would be very helpful.

```
          Has Age   Null age
Male       x        1-x
Female     y        1-y
```

How can I do that in Pandas?

Thank you!

Comment: What is x and 1-x in output? Can't you simple do `df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].mean()`

Comment: Thanks @YOLO I never used groupby in Pandas so I¨m not sure how this example works, but I see you´re using a mean and I just want to know how many (or the % of) missing values in the age column, split by sex. There's no value to calculate a mean there. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.sex,df.age.isnull())
Out[86]: 
age  False  True 
sex              
F        1      0
M        1      1
```

To get your output

```
s=pd.crosstab(df.sex,df.age.isnull())
s=s.div(s.sum(1),0)
s
Out[98]: 
age  False  True 
sex              
F      1.0    0.0
M      0.5    0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you start with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': [20, 40, 40, None, 18], 
    'sex': [None, 'F', 'M', 'M', None]})
```

Then you can use

```
>>> df.age.isnull().groupby(df.sex).value_counts().to_frame().unstack()
    age
age False   True
sex     
F   1.0 NaN
M   1.0 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, to calculate % of missing values split by sex, you can do:

```
df.groupby('sex')['age'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum() / len(x))

sex
F    0.0
M    0.5
```